# how to create sub menu below menu item in silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

how to create sub menu below menu item in silverlight 4
my code is as below

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu1" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="menu1" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="30"  >

            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item1"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item1" Header="Item 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Background="#0041E4F2" BorderBrush="#00E6FFFF" AllowDrop="True" />
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>

        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu2" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="menu2" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="30" >
        <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item2" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item2" Header="Item 2" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
        </toolkit:ContextMenu>

        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="menu3" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="30">
            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item3" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item3" Header="Item 3" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />


                    <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Item4" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Item4" Header="Item 4" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />



        </toolkit:ContextMenu>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature isn't supported by the current ContextMenu control. You can find more information in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/15/alive-and-kickin-new-silverlight-4-toolkit-released-with-today-s-silverlight-4-rtw.aspx)

> That said, please pay attention to the
>   word "subset"; the Toolkit's
>   ContextMenu doesn't have all the
>   features of WPF's quite yet. Notably,
>   it doesn't support multi-level menu
>   item nesting. However, none of the
>   customers I asked felt that nesting
>   was necessary right now, so I don't
>   expect its absence to be a big
>   limitation.

You can also find more information about the control and a possible way to simulate the feature [in this article on SilverlightShow](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Anatomy-of-the-ContextMenu-how-it-is-made-how-to-use-it-and-how-to-abuse-it.aspx). However, the solution doesn't look as expected, so I'm not sure if you will find it useful.